# Calculate renewal date DAX

Tags: datetime, time, dax

I have a datetime column (starting_date) in a PowerPivot model. I would like to calculate a field showing how many months until next renewal date. Each **year** a renewal is coming up?

Does somebody have an idea on how to do that dynamically in DAX?

Comment: We'll need a lot more information to help figure this out. What determines the renewal date? etc.

Comment: 'Starting date' + 1 Year (12 months) every future year. I know that DAX has the EDate function but it only does it for the next upcoming period!?

Comment: Is it possible to calculate knowing only the starting date and the length of renewal?

Comment: You could easily calculate the first renewal date. Repeated renewal dates becomes tricky. Which are you hoping to accomplish? And are you looking for a measure, or a calculated column?

Comment: I know how to calculate the next year after the starting date. But i am hoping to do a calculated field that works in for n years.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, are you looking for the first renewal date, or the next renewal date based on today (or another inputted date)?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. I am very interested in a calculated field indicating next renewal date (or days until next renewal) with respect to todays date.

Comment: Maybe if someone could help convert this into DAX:   SELECT * 
,CASE WHEN BirthdayThisYear>=NOW() THEN BirthdayThisYear ELSE BirthdayThisYear + INTERVAL 1 YEAR END AS NextBirthday
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    ,birthday - INTERVAL YEAR(birthday) YEAR + INTERVAL YEAR(NOW()) YEAR AS BirthdayThisYear
    FROM bd
) AS bdv
ORDER BY NextBirthday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent any example data, I set up the following table - Table1 (with the assumption that each Customer can only appear once)

```
Customer    starting_date
a           1/1/2014
b           2/25/2014
c           1/1/2015
d           4/1/2014
```

Then in PowerPivot I set up the following measures:

**[StartingDate]** - Used to return the customer's start date

```
StartingDate:=MAX(Table1[starting_date])
```

**[BirthdayThisYear]** - To set date for the current year

```
BirthdayThisYear:=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH([StartingDate]),DAY([StartingDate]))
```

**[ThisYearBeforeToday]** - Test if [BirthdayThisYear] is before `TODAY()`

```
ThisYearBeforeToday:=if([BirthdayThisYear]<today(),"yes","no")
```

**[NextRenewalDate]** - Use [ThisYearBeforeToday] to calculate next renewal date

```
NextRenewalDate:=IF([ThisYearBeforeToday]="yes",DATE(YEAR([BirthdayThisYear])+1,MONTH([BirthdayThisYear]),DAY([BirthdayThisYear])),[BirthdayThisYear])
```

---

You could do all the above in one step, but I find it difficult to debug later and hard to read. It could also likely be done more cleanly, but it works (as I understand your requirements)